# Невозможно открыть вторую форму в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При переходе на другую форму в Qt у меня возникает ошибка:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний
>   символ "public: __thiscall SecondWindow::SecondWindow(class QWidget
>   *)" (??0SecondWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) в функции "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

С чем она связана? Я добавил `"secondwindow.h"`, что еще нужно сделать, чтобы спокойно открыть новое окно?
Код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "secondwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    SecondWindow window;
    window.setModal(true);
    window.exec();
}
```

SecondWindow это просто пустая форма, собранная QT автоматически

Comment: Что бы открыть новое окно нужно показать код файла проекта, код инициализации ```SecondWindow```, код ```MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)```

Comment: Код вы, конечно, нам не покажете?

Comment: A secondwindow.cpp добавили? Ошибка говорит о том, что отсутствует определение конструктора второго окна, только есть объявление в заголовочном файле